# How can I speed up my Python for loop that goes through rows of lists?

Tags: python

This is my current code

```
df['company_id'] = ''
length = 0
while length < len(df):
  for x in df:
    if df['associations.companies.results'][length] == 'nan':
      df.loc[df['associations.companies.results'] == 'nan', 'company_id'] = 0  
    else:
      df['company_id'][length] = df['associations.companies.results'][length][0]['id']
  length = length +1
```

I tried to run this code with Lambda and np.where versions, however, these gave errors that I couldn't solve.
The data set has close to 40 rows and I try to get the company ID out of a dict nested in a list.
It looks like this on each row:

```
[{'id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'type': 'call_to_company'}]
```

sometimes there is no company_id and it will look like:

```
nan
```

The final result would be a separate column called "company_id" that contains the 'id' value.

Right now the code has been running for 30 mins and still going strong

Hope anyone can help.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please include an example of your df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various improvements that you could make, but i'm still not entirely sure what kind of output you are expecting.

First of all you execute the `len()` function at each iteration, because you put it in the header of the `while` loop, this is an error, since you need to execute it only once.

Second: you have a double `for` loop (I think because you wanted to iterate both through indexes and for the elements), but this is a big error since this way you have a O(n^2) complexity instead of a O(n) one.
You could've use `enumerate(df)` or simply use only the indexes

```py
df['company_id'] = ''

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['associations.companies.results'][i] == 'nan':
      df.loc[df['associations.companies.results'] == 'nan', 'company_id'] = 0  
    else:
      df['company_id'][i] = df['associations.companies.results'][i][0]['id']
```

I'm sure this could be further improved with lists comprehension or DataFrame `.apply()`, but I still don't understand your goal, so this is the most I can do.

If you've never heard before of Big-O notation I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/9419492)

Comment: You absolute hero! Did the job in 2 mins.
I am going to check that article now! Thanks for being so helpful

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood your use case, so here is my idea:

Try using `foreach` and `enumerate()`! With this, you can totally avoid having a counter variable.

Like so:

```
df['company_id'] = ''
for i, x in enumerate(df):
    if df['associations.companies.results'][i] == 'nan':
        df.loc[df['associations.companies.results'] == 'nan', 'company_id'] = 0  

    else:
        df['company_id'][i] = df['associations.companies.results'][i][0]['id']
```

Sadly, your code is not so reproducible, so I hope I was able to understand

Comment: Dude, thank you so much for your fast response!
so the code runs, however it only fills the if statement. The copany_id column stays empty.

What can I do to make the code more reproducable?

Comment: please add an example of your df variable. I was forced to use your example! Try using my code but replacing my df declaration with yours